# Button for markupCore extension not showing in dockingpanel

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have followed Philippe Leefsma's tutorial on how to implement the markup tool, but without any luck. Link here: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/playing-with-the-new-view-data-markup-api.html

and here: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/docs/tutorial-feature_markup.html

I get errors that I need to include requireJS, but I don't want to use it. So instead I used this script in my html file:

```
<script src="https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/2.2/extensions/MarkupsCore.js">
```

I don't know if this is the right way to go? I get no errors in the console, but the markup button doesn't show up in the dockingpanel.

This is my code for loading the extension in the viewer:

```
viewerApp = null;

function initializeViewer(containerId, urn, params) {
function getToken(url) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        $.get(url, function (response) {
            resolve(response.access_token);
        });
    });
}
var initOptions = {
    documentId: 'urn:' + urn,
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    getAccessToken: function (onGetAccessToken) {
        getToken(params.gettokenurl).then(function (val) {
            var accessToken = val;
            var expireTimeSeconds = 60 * 30;
            onGetAccessToken(accessToken, expireTimeSeconds);
        });
    }
}

function onDocumentLoaded(doc) {
    var rootItem = doc.getRootItem();
    // Grab all 3D items
    var geometryItems3d =
      Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(
        rootItem, { 'type': 'geometry', 'role': '3d' }, true);
    // Grab all 2D items
    var geometryItems2d =
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(
        rootItem, { 'type': 'geometry', 'role': '2d' }, true);
    // Pick the first 3D item otherwise first 2D item
    var selectedItem = (geometryItems3d.length ?
            geometryItems3d[0] :
            geometryItems2d[0]);

    var domContainer = document.getElementById('viewerContainer');

    var config = { extensions: ["Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore"] };

    // GUI Version: viewer with controls
    var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(domContainer, config);
    viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore");

    viewer.initialize();

    viewer.loadModel(doc.getViewablePath(selectedItem));

    var extension = viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore");

    viewerApp = viewer;


}

function onEnvInitialized() {
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
      initOptions.documentId,
      function (doc) {
          onDocumentLoaded(doc);
      },
      function (errCode) {
          onLoadError(errCode);
      })
}

function onLoadError(errCode) {
    console.log('Error loading document: ' + errCode);
}

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(
  initOptions,
  function () {
      onEnvInitialized()
  })
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there has been a few changes to the API since I wrote that blog post. The MarkupCore.js is now included in the viewer3D.js source, so you don't need to reference any extra file or use requireJS if you use the latest version of the viewer API.

Keep in mind that this is an API-only feature, so even after loading the markup extension, you won't get any UI out of the box. You have to implemented it yourself, for example create a dialog with buttons that may eventually create markups by calling the API.

Some of the code from my blog post may still be valid and give you an idea about what you need to do.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. I'll just simply try to implement this logic. Thank you very much for your answer, Philippe!

Comment: Welcome, feel free to post your questions if you face any trouble when using the API ;)